# Electric Meter Runs Backwards

Tags: electrical, meter

The service for the site was recently upgraded from 200 amps to 400 amps service.  The sub-panels were re-run from the new panel.  There are now a 200 amp panel, and two 100 amp panels.

I decided that I would like to know how much electricity is used on one of the 100 amp panels, so I put the old meter base in line ahead of that panel and purchased a used electric meter.

However, when I plugged it in, it runs backwards.  I cannot tell why and could use some help.

Here is a picture of the meter base inside and out.

[image: Outside meter base]
[image: Inside meter base]

Answer (score 13):

Put the meter in upside down. If that works, then you can reverse the wiring or live with an upside down meter.

Also, since the meter is just for your own use, running backwards is fine. The math is just a bit different.

Comment: Yeah, most meters want incoming power coming in the top.

Comment: Since this is an electro-mechanical meter, I wouldn't leave it installed upside down. The bearings for the meter disk may not be designed for that and could add error to the energy measurement. If it were a solid-state meter, no problem.